# Error: Se ha agotado el tiempo mientras se esperaba la respuesta del usuario

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Al tratar de enviar varios *Mails* se dispara este error. Cómo puedo comenzar a arreglar el error que dice: "Se ha agotado el tiempo mientras se esperaba la respuesta del usuario". A veces funciona y a veces no sale el bug.

Este es mi código:

```
function onEdit(evt){
  var range=evt.range;
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
  var texto=worksheet.getRange( range.getRow(),range.getColumn()).getValue();//numero gestores para iniciar bucle//

  //si es fila 26//
  if(range.getColumn()==26){


  //averiguamos cuantos admins hay
  var style = get_status(texto);
  worksheet.getRange( range.getRow(),range.getColumn()).setValue(texto).setBackgroundColor(style[0].color);


  var admins=list_admins(worksheet.getRange('E'+ range.getRow()).getValue());
  var nnotificados=admins.length; 
   var response = ui.alert('Desea notificar al remitente vía mail', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    // Process the user's response.
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
      Logger.log('Enviaron a:');
      for (var i=0;i<nnotificados;i++){
       // ui.alert(template_change_status(admins[i],range,worksheet,style[0].color));
        //si el asunto es finzalizada no lio
        var asunto="";

        if("Finalizado Cargue al LMS" == worksheet.getRange('Z'+ range.getRow()).getValue()  ){
          asunto=worksheet.getRange('Z'+ range.getRow()).getValue();
        }else{
          asunto=worksheet.getRange('Z'+ range.getRow()).getValue()+" N: "+worksheet.getRange('AC'+ range.getRow()).getValue()+ " Ficha: "+worksheet.getRange('D'+ range.getRow()).getValue()+ " Ticket: "+worksheet.getRange('X'+ range.getRow()).getValue();
        }

        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to:admins[i].email,
          subject:asunto,
          htmlBody:template_change_status(admins[i],range,worksheet,style[0].color)
        });


      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error significa que hay un elemento de interfaz de usuario que está en espera de respuesta pero esto ocurre de forma sincrónica por lo que el tiempo de ejecución sigue transcurriendo.

Si requieres que la espera no tenga tiempo límite, entonces debes cambiar la lógica de tu script, por ejemplo, en lugar de usar un activador simple al editar (onEdit) usa un elemento de interfaz que haga el envío cuando así lo indique el usuario.